# How to create a secure login to protect the password information

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website which will be open to the public. In other projects I've never had worry with the way that the login was made​​, but in this case it is important. 
Is there any way to protect the information being sent to the server, to prevent sniff the network and thus capture the login and password openly?

Additional information: the site is in ASP.NET MVC 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's call HTTPS. If you get a cert for your domain and apply it to your site in IIS, and of course, require HTTPS on the any auth actions. Then, the traffic will be encrypted end-to-end. It's not *unbreakable* mind you, but it's really all there is and is largely effective, unless you leak your private key or the client's computer has been compromised in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
Html.AntiForgeryToken();
```

in your view, where you have the form, and then use the data annotation

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

in your controller method where the POST action is, and for SSL add the data annotation

```
[RequireHttps]
```

in the same method

Comment: Anti-forgery tokens have nothing to do with data going over the line unencrypted. They're still important, but for a completely different and unrelated reason: CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use an SSL certificate.